# Sort by least played song

Tags: itunes, music, playlist

I have a playlist with ~200 songs, I use this playlist during my (1-2hr) workout, it seems that when I start the playlist I hear a few songs I heard the day before.  I don't want to listen again to the songs I heard yesterday...yes I could just hit >> to advance to the next song but that interrupts my workout.  Is there a sort option that would play the least played song next in a playlist?

Comment: Is this on iPhone or on a Mac or Windows PC?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about being able to reverse sort by Number of Plays, but you can exclude anything played in the last *x* days with a Smart Playlist...

For example...

[image]

Comment: Reverse sort by number plays works just click on the Number of playes header.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I see this option with iTunes on my PC and Mac, but i have my iPhone with me during my workout....how is this done from my iPhone?